# Elements of different heights suiting the div

Tags: html, css

stackoverflow users.

I'm on my way to create a responsive design, but here comes one problem. My design is based on the list schema:

```
<ul>
<li>First element code</li>
<li>Second element code</li>
(and so on (up to 20-30 elements)
</ul>
```

So basically those elments are with float attribute, so they are next to each other, as long as the page width lets them. My problem is that they have **different heights**. Example:

```
**First LI*****       **Second LI******
***************       *****************
***************       *****************
***************       
***************       

**Third LI*****       **Fourth LI******
***************       *****************
***************       *****************
***************       *****************
***************       ***************
```

Two column layout. The first li element (first column) has bigger height than one in the second column. The element below from the first column is right under it, but the second element doesnt fit in the space (which is left because the first element in the second column has lesser height) and is located next to the second element in the first column.

I want to achieve:

```
**First LI*****       **Second LI******
***************       *****************
***************       *****************
***************       **Fourth LI******
***************       *****************
**Third LI*****       *****************
***************       *****************
*************** 
*************** 
***************
```

If it's possible, automatically. Do I have to use column grid or can I achieve something like that the other way? I hope I made my question clear, sorry for my English - I am from Poland.

Looking forward for hearing the answer from you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that sort of alignment I think you are pretty much stuck with something like Isotope - http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ or Masonry - http://masonry.desandro.com/.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful links. Are those scripts slowing website much? I mean: is it better to have a bit uglier design without one of those scripts or to have a nice design with one of them? Is the difference in loading time significant?

Comment: It really depends on the design you are aiming for but in my experience the scripts aren't too heavy to use either.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it would be to have your columns horizontal and with `display: block`. This way they will go onto the next line and have an equal height like you want

Comment: This is how it currently works: first li has 60% of width, second 40% of width - it's the height that differs. I dont have any columns, just a li elements. Shall i use bootstrap-like columns?